# Merging DataTable rows in an RDLC/ReportViewer output

Tags: c#, datatable, rdlc, reportviewer

I've been set work involving RDLC files.

My data source (data table) for the ReportViewer sends rows in the format shown below:

> Client A - Product 1 - Summed Total of Product 1 Sales
> Client A - Product 2 - Summed Total of Product 2 Sales
> Client A - Product 3 - Summed Total of Product 3 Sales
>
> Client B - Product 1 - Summed Total of Product 1 Sales
> Client B - Product 2 - Summed Total of Product 2 Sales
> Client B - Product 3 - Summed Total of Product 3 Sales

And so on...
My question is, can RDLC/ReportViewer be used to easily output this data into the following format:

> Client A - Summed Total of Product 1 - Summed Total of Product 2 - Summed Total of Product 3
> Client B - Summed Total of Product 1 - Summed Total of Product 2 - Summed Total of Product 3

Comment: You would have to create another dataset with in visual studio, joining the two data tables above. Then create a third table in the report and do sum row/columns. Theoretically it should work, but considering a lot of features of Reportviewer "should work" and don't, you won't know till you try.